# Delphi checking date to make backup files on a scheduled

Tags: delphi, zip, backup, scheduled-tasks

I have a program that writes to a log file and zips it. I want to set it up so that it will take the log file and zip it after a month and clear the file and reset it to do it again if another month has passed

```
procedure SendToLog(Const MType : twcMTypes; Const callProgram, callPas, callProssecs, EMessage, zipName : String; AddlStr : String = '' );
Const
  MTValues = 'EDS';
var
  LogFile      : TextFile;
  LogName      : String;
  EString      : String;
begin
  logName := WebLogPath;              // þ for delimeter
  EString := MTValues[ Ord( MType )+1] + PC + FormatDateTime( 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss.zzz', Now )
     + PC + callProgram + PC + callpas + PC + callProssecs + PC + EMessage;
  Assign( LogFile, LogName );
  if FileExists(LogName) then
    Append( LogFile )   { Open to Append }
  else
  begin
    Rewrite( LogFile );   { Create file }
  end;
  Writeln( LogFile, EString );
  Close( LogFile );
  ArchiveFiles('C:', 'mytest.log', 'C:', zipName + '.zip', 'M');
```

I want to know how I make so that every time the program logs something it checks if the a month has passed then it will zip everything into a new file and reset the log.

Comment: Isn't this better done at the OS level by setting up a recurrent process and a small batch/shell script? It would be one line to compress the file and one more to delete the old log file - or only one total if your compression tool has an option to move the added file into the archive.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to either:

1. keep track of the last write date somewhere, persistently across app restarts.
2. query the last write date of the log file itself using the Win32 API [`GetFileTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.
3. put the current date on each log entry that you write, then you can seek to the end of the log file and read the date from the last log entry that was written.

Each time you want to write a new log entry, compare the month+year of the last known date against the current date and then zip+reset the log file if the current date is higher.

Answer (score 0):

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.GetCreationTime
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.AppendAllText
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.Exists

So you just check for creation date and then you decide if you need a new file or not.

```
procedure SendToLog(Const MType : twcMTypes; Const callProgram, callPas, callProssecs, EMessage, zipName : String; AddlStr : String = '' );
Const
  MTValues = 'EDS';
  MaxAgeBeforeNewLogFile = 30; // 30 days, in TDateTime type convention
var
  LogFile      : TextFile;
  LogName      : String;
  EString      : String;
  NeedZipLogFile : Boolean; ZipName: String;
begin
  logName := WebLogPath;              // þ for delimeter
  EString := MTValues[ Ord( MType )+1] + PC + FormatDateTime( 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss.zzz', Now )
     + PC + callProgram + PC + callpas + PC + callProssecs + PC + EMessage;

  NeedZipLogFile := False;
  if System.IOUtils.TFile.Exists( LogName ) then
     NeedZipLogFile := Now() - System.IOUtils.TFile.GetCreationTime( LogName ) 
                        > MaxAgeBeforeNewLogFile;


  if NeedZipLogFile then begin
     ZipName := _Generate_New_Non_Used_And_Proper_Name_For_Archive();
     _Save_Log_Into_Zip( LogName );

     If _Secure_Keeping_Of_Logs_Is_Very_Very_Important then begin
        _Flush_Windows_File_Cache_To_Disk( ZipName );
        _Read_Zipped_Log_Into_Memory( ZipName, ExtractFileName( LogName ), _Temp_Memory_Buffer );
        _Compare_With_Old_Log_File_And_Ensure_Nothing_Was_Lost( LogName, _Temp_Memory_Buffer);
     end;

     DeleteFile( LogFile);
  end;

  System.IOUtils.TFile.AppendAllText( LogFile, EString );
end;
```